# SQL query returning events with an odd number of users assigned to them

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 5 tables--users, groups, events, users_groups_link, users_events_link. Like so:

```
users
user_id

groups
group_id

events
event_id

users_groups_link
user_id
group_id

users_events_link
user_id
event_id
```

Each event has 2 or 4 groups assigned to it and each group contains 8-11 users. user_id=1 is a group vacancy. **I'm wanting to make sure that each event has an even number of users so I'm trying to create a query that returns all events containing an odd number of users.** So far I have this:

```
SELECT user_id,event_id 
FROM users,groups,events,users_events_link,users_groups_link
WHERE users.user_id=users_events_link.user_id
AND events.event_id=users_events_link.event_id
AND users.user_id=users_groups_link.user_id
AND groups.group_id=users_groups_link.group_id
AND user_id <> 1
```

which returns all events and users that are assigned to them (via their host group) like so:

```
user_id         event_id
56              1001
34              1001
76              1001
45              1001
87              1001
88              1001
54              1001
4               1001
63              1002
69              1002
77              1002
etc.
```

Now I'm wanting to refine this query further by just returning events with an odd number of users assigned to them i.e. events with their id in the right hand column repeating an odd number of times. And then maybe refining it further by eliminating the users_id column entirely and returning one event id for each event containing an odd number of users.

I've tried using "count()" and "group by" but am not getting the desired results so i'm obviously doing something wrong but I don't know what. Thanks in advance.

Comment: And your desired result is ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of `COUNT`, `HAVING` and the modulo operator:

```
SELECT event_id, COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) as c
FROM users,groups,events,users_events_link,users_groups_link
WHERE users.user_id=users_events_link.user_id
AND events.event_id=users_events_link.event_id
AND users.user_id=users_groups_link.user_id
AND groups.group_id=users_groups_link.group_id
AND user_id <> 1
GROUP BY event_id
HAVING c % 2 = 1
```

Comment: Beautiful. I tried this out and it worked perfectly. Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome. Perhaps you mark this answer as accepted so other people looking for the same thing can find it easier?

Answer (score 0):

Since you insisted on changing your current query I did that, but there is simplier way to achieve this result - without derived table and more clear - using `JOINs`.

[Modulo operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) is what you are looking for. In SQL it's `%`.

This query will give you `event_id's` that have odd number of `users` and tell you their cardinality on each particular event.

```
SELECT event_id, COUNT(DISTINCT user_id)
FROM(
  SELECT user_id,event_id 
  FROM users,groups,events,users_events_link,users_groups_link
  WHERE users.user_id=users_events_link.user_id
  AND events.event_id=users_events_link.event_id
  AND users.user_id=users_groups_link.user_id
  AND groups.group_id=users_groups_link.group_id
  AND user_id <> 1
  ) foo
GROUP BY event_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) % 2 = 1
```

If you have distinct `user_id's` you can skip the `DISTINCT` keyword. I'm not familiar with schema of your tables - better safe than sorry.